# Given n points in two views, how can I recover the angle of rotation of the camera to achieve the second view?

Tags: opencv, camera, computer-vision, computational-geometry, multiview

let's say that all we have are corresponding image points in two views. From these points, I can compute a homography/essential matrix, however extracting the angle of rotation of the camera is not understood.

Comment: Did you already have a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485774/rotation-matrix-opencv

Comment: that will get you rotation around z, is that all you need?  Getting rotation around x and y from just a homography is harder than you might expect

Comment: @Hammer you're right, the rotation matrix being calculated in that question is for 2D (essentially the rotation of an image). I'm looking for the rotation of the camera.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I have misunderstood your question but if you are looking are looking for the rotation matrix between two camera coordinate systems and have computed the essential matrix then the rotation matrix can be calculated by taking an SVD of the essential matrix and doing some simple matrix multiplication.

The algorithm is listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_matrix#Determining_R_and_t_from_E).